# How to filter PHP opener?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I've been searching the web and in this great forum but I didn't find anything.

I got some issue with a code higlighter plugin. Everything is fine except that some php tags do not work properly :

```
<!--?php instead of <?php
```

It just breaks markup !
**I only use HTML Editor**.

How can I manage to make it work?

EDIT: in the meantime I just changed plugin and it works fine but I'm curious to know how to solve this issue. The plugin is [Google Syntax Highlighter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/) (verry old I know)

Comment: What's the plugin? What have you tried?

Comment: At the very least, add a link to the particular plugin you are using.

Comment: sorry I missed that-> I edit

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is breaking the tag and not WordPress formatting function?

Comment: I do not really know, I use some remove_filter() to prevent WP from formatting content. Besides the plugin uses exclusively javaScript to render code, I was expecting some htmlspecialchars() and/or str_replace(). I'm not saying it's better but I do not want content display to depend on js.